# How do you read/pronounce date colloquially in the USA?

Tags: dates

**4th Feb 2018** is pronounced like that in my language: **four two two thousand eighteen**

I know that in America it's pronounced like **Feb forth two thousand eighteen** but this is considered very very formal in my language.

Is there any colloquial way in America where mention the **month's number** instead of its name or where you use **cardinal numbers** instead of ordinal ones?

Do you colloquially say **two thousand eighteen** or **two thousand *(and)* eighteen** or **twenty eighteen**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colloquially in the US:

4th Feb 2018  could be spoken as

*The fourth of February | February fourth*

*twenty eighteen |  two thousand eighteen*

We might offer only numbers for the day, month and year but typically not when reading the month-names spelled out from a piece of paper:

What's your date of birth?

*five sixteen eighty-eight*

*five sixteen nineteen eighty-eight*